# Extracting unique values from raster in area using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I have Landcover raster and thousand points. I want to create buffer  around each point a extract all unqiue values in buffer from Landcover raster.

Do you know how can it be done using ArcGIS Desktop?

An example of what I want to create is in this picture.

[image]

Comment: I think you can do this with simple scripting outside of qgis. Also, your buffer appears to be lopsided: why doesn't it include the row above the circled number? Is that intentional?

Comment: Once you collect the array of data within the window (e.g. `[1,1,1,1,3,5]`), what do you hope to do with the values? Are you going to summarize the data somehow? I'm curious if ArcGIS focal statistics would suit your needs?

Comment: thanks,    buffer from picture is only example. i need only extract values from buffer for statistic. Focal statistic can not save unique values, only number of unique values.